# Updating a MS Access database from NetBeans, only able to update the first and third records, not the rest

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, netbeans

I have built a GUI in NetBeans to edit a MS Access database, I am able to successfully connect and update all of the tables in the database except one. With the table in question, I am only able to update the first and third rows, when attempting to update the other rows I receive the following error:

*Update btn Candidates Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''...100  character String...' WHERE CID = 5'*

The code for the method performing the update is as follows:

```
 private void btnUp2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
      try{ 
int CID = Integer.parseInt(txtCID.getText());

String FNC = txtFNC.getText();
String SNC = txtSNC.getText();
String ClasC = txtClaC.getText();
int Age= Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText());
String Mot = txtMot.getText();

String sql = "UPDATE tblCandidates SET FirstName = '"+FNC+"',Surname ='"+SNC+"',Class ='"+ClasC+"', Age= "+Age+", Motivation ='"+Mot+"' WHERE CID = "+CID+"" ;
System.out.println(sql);//Note this was used as part of my debugging
obj.updateTbl(sql);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Update Successful"); 
}catch(Exception e)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error, Check Fields");     
System.out.println("Update btn Candidates Error: "+e.getMessage());
}         
    }
```

The programme connects to the database correctly and updates all other tables successfully using similar code (just changing table, field and variable names basically). I can't seem to understand why only the 1st and 3rd records would be updated. Any help would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: WHERE CID = "+CID+"" ? plus what?

Comment: CID is the int I declared at the top of the method. the ++ is to use the variable in the query, at least that was the intention.

Comment: but you only need:  `WHERE CID = "+CID;`  This prolly doesn't solve the problem, however.

Comment: Thanks, but it hasn't solved the problem, any other suggestions?

Comment: can you show the 100 character String, and the output of the debug sql line?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've fixed the error, I re-entered all the records into the table and it seems to have solved the problem.